# How to keep a TypeScript interface in sync with a Zod schema?

Tags: typescript, zod

I have an existing project primarily written in TypeScript where we originally had no runtime validations for our data. As we're expanding our API and also have JavaScript users, I've decided to introduce Zod to validate our data at runtime.

**Example**

```
import { z } from 'zod';

interface MyData {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  isStudent?: boolean;
}

const MyDataSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number(),
  isStudent: z.boolean().optional()
});
```

The challenge I'm facing is keeping the `MyData` interface and the `MyDataSchema` in sync. Every time I update the TypeScript interface, I have to manually update the Zod schema. This manual process is error-prone and can lead to inconsistencies.

I tried using `satisfies z.ZodType<MyTypescriptType>` (example below), but it doesn't handle optional types well.

```
const MyDataSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number(),
  isStudent: z.boolean().optional()
}) satisfies z.ZodType<MyData>;
```

Is there an efficient way to enforce synchronization between a TypeScript interface and a Zod schema? Ideally, I'd like an approach where updating the interface would either automatically update the schema or at least throw an error if they're out of sync.

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-to-zod)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM This tool is not mature enough. Sometimes it doesn't generate the types correctly and still has many limitations such as support for generics.

Comment: Can you elaborate why ZodType doesn't work for you? It works with the example: https://tsplay.dev/mZyVKN

Comment: @katniss  if you set the age field as optional using age?: number, you won't get any alerts. Another example, if you completely remove the age field from the TypeScript type, nothing will show up. Hope that helps!

Comment: are you dead set on doing it this way around? you could infer the type from the schema instead

Comment: @Hoopra I have already written all my typescript types. It will be a waste of time to re write everything in zod.

Comment: @William fair enough. You could still export the same type by inferring from the schema using `z.infer<typeof Schema>` and just deleting the interface. then your other code would error if the types are not the same (probably). just a suggestion

Comment: But you must have the schema already, if you need to keep it in sync with the type? Then you just define the type from that using Zod's `infer` helper, as Hoopra said.

Comment: If  not, you would probably have to use a cursed assertion like this: https://tsplay.dev/N7QVDW

Comment: Instead of trying type inference, or using any 3rd party tool, I would consider forcing the schema to look like the interface !
I would do like this :
`const MyDataSchema: z.ZodType<MyData> = ...`